# Google Spreadsheet vlookup with arrayformula PLUS multiplication of returned value(s)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have my VLOOKUP with ArrayFormula working thanks to Adam's (AD:AM) brilliantly spelled-out solution ([https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docs/parallel$20lookup$20solution/docs/36A0epDlIdE/qnywZst0DioJ](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docs/parallel%2420lookup%2420solution/docs/36A0epDlIdE/qnywZst0DioJ))

So in col J this is what I have:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(H2:H;ProductTable!A2:C;3*SIGN(ROW(H2:H));FALSE))
```

Works great. However, I would like to then take the returned value(s) from that formula in col J and multiply it against the Qty value(s) that are in row I.

Obviously I could add an extra helper column in col K...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(I2:I*J2:J)
```

...but I was hoping to avoid adding yet another column to my Query results, especially since the returned results in col J have no visible purpose on the worksheet - they are meant to be used strictly for mathematical purposes only.

I've attempted multiple ways of slipping that formula into the ArrayFormula / VLOOKUP function in col J, but I've had no luck thus far.

Maybe it can't be done(?), or maybe I could just benefit from a fresh set of eyes looking at this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I'm not sure why this didn't appear to work when I had tried it before, but out of desperation I just walked away for a while, and then just re-tried everything again.
And *this* time I get the results that I was looking for:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(H2:H;Backend_Product!A2:C;3*SIGN( ROW(G2:G));FALSE )*I2:I)
```

(a bit of a DUH, so maybe I had originally referenced the wrong column or something)

Answer (score 1):

The post you referenced is from 2011. I think that use case has been resolved since then.

I have a column using the formula `=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(J$2:J,$C$2:$D,2,FALSE))`. I created a check column with `=VLOOKUP(J2,$C$2:$D,2,FALSE)` which I dragged down a number of rows.

It appears that, in the array formula, `J` is being iterated just as it is in my dragged formula, while `C:D` are fixed. Both the original column and check column have the same result data so far as I've dragged the check column down.

Caveat: I did not do an exhaustive search or create a particularly clever test case. I just eyeballed a good heaping of rows of actual data.