# Google Sheets Query return null rows

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a question regarding google sheets query command, best demonstrated by the following link to a sample sheet:

[Sample Query](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PJK6Y10iSYT-gKn_AN0H93zFobced2327XnK2YDf12w/edit#gid=0)

The idea is that I have group column (groups 1, 2, and 3) in Column A and values in Column B (some arbitrary numbers). So I query a sum where B = 2, where the output will be  Group 1 has 2 and Group 3 has 4. Group 2 should have 0 (this is much clearer in the sheet).

Normal Query results in a 2x2 table with Groups 1 and 3 (and their sums), and they omit Group 2. Is there away to not omit Group 2? I am not picky if it shows up with a 0 (preferred) or a null or #N/A... I just want it to read:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Group</td>
<td>sum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td><td>0 or Null or #N/A or Blank</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

instead of

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Group</td>
<td>sum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like creating a dummy table may be the way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657130/google-sheets-query-language-return-0?rq=1

is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a different way?

Many. In my opinion the most sensible of which is to apply UNIQUE and SUMIFS instead.

However with QUERY there is no need for a separate table and such a long formula as your example:

```
=query(A:B,"select A,sum(B) where (B is NULL or B=2) group by A")
```

should serve (saves 84 characters as well as the extra table), provided you just include an 'A' value of `2` (with corresponding 'B' blank) in your data.

For your preferred option, make the corresponding 'B' `0` and change `is null` to `=0`.